# Ubuntu is not booting - "No init fount. Try passing init= bootarg." , Install from Windows (Wubi)

Tags: boot, wubi

Ubuntu 10.04 installed from Windows 7 (Wubi filesystme), Now Ubuntu is not booting giving this error.

```
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init fount. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu7) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of build in commands

(initramfs)
```

I looked at [the suggestions here](http://learntoconfigure.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/ubuntu-cannot-boot-no-init-found-try-passing-initbootarg/).That can't solved my problem because Ubuntu is installed from Windows and all the drive shows of Windows. How can I get this to boot?

Comment: Was it running fine before or did it happen right after you installed? If it was running fine before, was there some event that preceded this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) under the section "How can I access my Wubi install and repair my install if it won't boot?"

---

It worked for me with little changes as below:

1. Boot using Ubuntu live USB/CD
2. Go in System -> Administration -> "Disk Utility" (For 10.04, for other Ubuntu version somehow reach to "Disk Utility")

   Make sure your partitions where Wubi created the `root.disk` file is mounded. If not, you have to mount it with the "Mount Volume" button.
3. You should see the root.disk here -

   `/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`

   (Note: In your case the name can be different for "host")
4. Perform file system check on this file as below:

   `sudo fsck /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`

   It corrects the corruption using the above command
5. Reboot the machine
6. Enjoy your Ubuntu