# Recent upgrade, now it says "no init found" on start up. Solutions posed in other threads not working

Tags: upgrade, init

My hard drive is partitioned to both windows and ubuntu. Recently, while logged into ubuntu, an upgrade was suggested. After upgrading, and upon rebooting, the screen reads an error "no init found. Try passing init=bootarg."

Following solutions in other threads I have created a Live USB. Running from the Live USB I have accessed the terminal and typed

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Here is the output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x74b5821f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   570632191   285212672    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       570632192  1422579711   425973760    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4      1422579712  1465147391    21283840   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda5       570634240  1422579711   425972736    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 4022 MB, 4022337024 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 489 cylinders, total 7856127 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          38     7839719     3919841    c  W95 FAT32         (LBA)
```

Next,

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

However, this returned the error:

```
fsck can't find fsck.ntfs
```

Per another thread's solution ([fsck can't find fsck.ntfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86086/fsck-cant-find-fsck-ntfs)) I typed:

```
sudo ln -nsf /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -nsf /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

Returning to

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

Outputs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ntfs: invalid option -- 'y'
ntfsfix v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)

Usage: ntfsfix [options] device
    Attempt to fix an NTFS partition.

    -b, --clear-bad-sectors Clear the bad sector list
    -d, --clear-dirty       Clear the volume dirty flag
    -h, --help              Display this help
    -n, --no-action         Do not write anything
    -V, --version           Display version information

For example: ntfsfix /dev/hda6

Developers' email address: ntfs-3g-devel@lists.sf.net
News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

So, trying it again without the -y flag returns:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.
```

This appears to be successful, however, upon rebooting I still get the same "no init found" error.

Sorry for the long post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your fdisk output doesn't show any linux partitions. Are you using the Windows Boot Manager for booting? Maybe, you installed Ubuntu with Wubi as Jun wrote in [his answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/781519/386067).

Comment: My mint is also gone with kern 5.10. Not yet found an answer, fsck does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Ubuntu with Wubi, you need to follow the answers here:

[Ubuntu is not booting - "No init fount. Try passing init= bootarg." , Install from Windows (Wubi)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228081/ubuntu-is-not-booting-no-init-fount-try-passing-init-bootarg-install-fr)